# I need a suggestion to separate two forms on user details

Tags: usability, user-behavior

I'm working on a tutor website and after the user sign up, I send the user to edit his profile. Here is the screen:

[image]

As you can see I have two forms, one for the user information and the other one for categories (in which category is this user offering tutoring). But I don't feel this is easy or friendly to use. So I want to ask you for suggestion, I mean what are the recommendation of UX-UI to separate and organize this form, because I need this forms to be easy to understand a easy to use.

Thanks

Comment: If your content was in English it would me more clear (for non-spanish speaking UX experts here) how to organize it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A Heading will do the trick.

You can just modify your form like this,

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWLRZR.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

> Also please provide the **labels** for each input field. That will help
>   the user a lot!!

## Option 2

You can go for ***Wizard.***

Have the user information in page 1 and the tutorial details on the next one where you will be submitting the form as well.

Espero que ayude!!